# Radial chart attributes

Tags: charts, lightning-components, attribute

I created a visualforce page which displays a radial chart. How can I change the number of lines of the chart? My chart displays always two lines per value 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, but I want to display just one. I thought "steps" will help, but unfortunately not.

is there a simple way to create this chart as a lighting component?

```
<apex:page sidebar="false" Controller="radar1" showHeader="true" id="pg">
<apex:chart height="300" width="300" legend="true" data="{!data}">
    <apex:legend position="bottom"/>
    <apex:axis type="Radial" steps="1" minimum="0" maximum="5" position="radial">
        <apex:chartLabel />
    </apex:axis>
    <apex:radarSeries xField="KSCName" yField="Score" tips="true" opacity="0.4" markerType="circle" />
</apex:chart>
</apex:page>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is there a simple way to create this chart as a lighting component?

One of the following approaches (which isn't difficult) should help you out to visualize radar chart in lightning component.

- You can use visualization JS libraries like [chartjs](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js) or [d3js](https://github.com/d3/d3), load them as static resources and create radar charts in lightning components. You can google out quite a few article on how to utilize these JS libraries to create radar charts.
- You can use the app exchange package [Lightning Web Chart.js Component](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N3u00000MBarPEAT). Its a open source project by Salesforce labs and available for free. I've not used this one, but seems promising.

> I thought "steps" will help, but unfortunately not.

As mentioned [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_axis.htm), `steps` attribute is `Valid only when the axis type is Numeric.` . Hence, its of no use for radial axis type. If you want to use VF charting, you should ignore the `steps` attribute and mark the `maximum` attribute as 10 or greater.

While I couldn't find any official documentation to support my following statement. `apex:axis` seems limited in case of radar chart visualization in VF pages.

- The # of radial lines or concentric circles always seems to be 10, regardless of the `maximum` & `minimum` integers. Seems like an undocumented limitation with radar charts in VF.
- The calculation of tick mark values on the radial axis seems to be auto-calculated and doesn't support decimals.

Considering the above 2 points, the `maximum` integer value should be always 10 or greater for the platform to determine meaningful tick mark values. For any `maximum` integer below 10, you can see that the tick mark values are incorrect (*my conclusion is that the VF platform is rounding up the tick mark values leading to this behavior*).